# Tabcontrol tabs order

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

in c#, winforms, I have a tabcontrol that contains some pages, I dont know how many, but I need to send one tab (addTab) always to the end, any hint how to do that?

Comment: You keep it at the end by using Insert() on tabs that you add.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the [TabPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpages.aspx) collection:

```
yourTabControl.TabPages.Remove(addTab);
yourTabControl.TabPages.Add(addTab);
```